# Where can I start in repairing this?

Tags: macbook-pro, display

This MacBook Pro was purchased in 2019 used and there is no warranty. It is a 13 inch MacBook Pro. There are horizontal colored lines running up the screen. I’ve restarted twice. I’m not asking for a direct explanation or anything elaborate. I’m asking what are the parts called that I should look at and would probably would need replacing. I’m gonna try to repair it myself.

I did leave my MacBook Pro in my backpack in my car in the heat for approximately 30 minutes. I imagine that the heat may have caused this problem. But what part would most be affected by heat.

[image]

Comment: your picture does not show any vertical lines, but I do see some horizontal lines. If your MacBook was purchased new in 2019 it is likely covered under warranty. If it was not purchased new then we need the model (Macbook Pro late 2015, 13 inch, etc.) to assist you in any way.

Comment: The part you need to replace is called the “display assembly.” To verify if it’s the actual display and not something in software, take a screenshot. If the lines are in the image, it’s a problem with the system, not the hardware.

Comment: @Allan I don't understand the second sentence of your comment. Do you mean if the lines are within a _window_, it's a problem with the system...?" The screenshot in the question is not clear enough for me to see if the lines extend outside the window.

Comment: @DavidSupportsMonica - The picture posted is not a screenshot, it's a photo of the screen. Comparing a photo to an actual screenshot taken in-system is a clear indicator as to where the problem lies, hardware or software.

Comment: @Tetsujin Thanks. Now I understand what you meant.

Comment: @allen that’s really smart. I took a screen shot and the lines do not appear on the image. Therefore, the problem is hardware(I think) thanks so much.